# Web API service not running after deployed on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have a  Web Api application.when i run  this application on localhost 
    then it is working good..for eg:- `[http://localhost:5034/].`

It gives defult page which i set in root.config(index page)after that 
    i am trying to access the one of the action of this serviceby this 
    URL `[http://localhost:5034/api/Products]`
    and this Action give the response in form of json successfully in localhost..

But when i deploy this service on IIS 7.5 I deployed this service then after when i trying to access the application by this URL`[http://localhost/WebAPIApplication/]`(This URL is deployed Application URL) then it gives a directory List insted of defult Page which i set in `root.config`

```
2/21/2013  3:17 PM        <dir> bin 
2/21/2013  3:17 PM        <dir> Content 
2/19/2013  3:36 PM        32038 favicon.ico 
2/19/2013  3:36 PM          112 Global.asax 
2/21/2013  3:17 PM        <dir> Images 
2/19/2013  3:36 PM         1431 packages.config 
2/21/2013  3:17 PM        <dir> Scripts 
2/21/2013  3:17 PM        <dir> Views 
2/21/2013  3:18 PM         5566 Web.config
```

Why i am not getting the Defult page? 
    and also when i trying to access Action of this service by this 
    URL`[http://localhost/WebAPIApplication/api/products]` then it give error :

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How can i solve both the Problem?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: for your directory listing point you can deny the directory listing in IIS

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you configured your Web API application in IIS to use a .NET 4 ASP.NET Application Pool.